# Creating an array in MIPS and adding the elemets

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, qtspim

*I want to create an array with these elements {16,2,77,40,12071}, and then find the sum of all elements. To do so i wrote the code below , but when i try to run it, it says that there is a syntax error at ".word" and I don't know how to fix it.
Please help!*

```
.data
foo: .word 16,2,77,40,12071


.text
.globl main

li $t0 , 0 #int n = 0
li $t1 , 0 #int sum = 0
la $t2 , foo # loading array adresses to t2 

main:

loop:
beq $t0 , 5 , end #branch to end if n = 5
lw $t3 , 0($t2) # get the first element of the array to t3
add $t1 ,$t1 , $t3 #the sum
addi $t0 , 1 # n++
add $t2 , $t2 , 4 # the next elemnt on the list
j loop

end:
#print the result
li $v0 , 1
move $a0 , $t1
syscall
# exit
li $v0 , 4
syscall
```

Comment: Also note instructions/code between `.text` and `main:` will be skipped and hence those there will not execute.

Comment: @ErikEidt Thank you very much , I was able to fix the code.